# how to always get the second select on droplist of url

Tags: html

I have these two url to go to.

1. url A
   https://tw.screener.finance.yahoo.net/future/aa03?opmr=optionfull&opcm=WTXO&opym=
2. url B
   https://tw.screener.finance.yahoo.net/future/aa03?opmr=optionfull&opcm=WTXO&opym=201912

url A, leaving blank after url ending &opym=

I would always get the first select on the dropdown list.

My question is on the url B : is there anyway that I can do to tell to always go to the second select on the dropdown list without know it is 201912?

Comment: No, not without creating a web scraper or knowing additional information about the handling of the parameter in the backend.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know fish11.